# mySQL: how to write a query that satisfies two or more conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given tables:

```
Departments: dept_id, dept_name
Employees: dept_id, emp_id, salary
```

I was trying to come up with ***a query that shows dept_id, dept_name, avg salary of specific depts, and number of employees in that dept. WHERE dept with less than 20 employees and average dept salary is less than 2000.***

Here is the query I came up to display employees with less than 2000 salary:

This is what i came up with for salary

```
SELECT dept_id, salary
FROM employees
WHERE (salary) < 2000;
```

And I know this can be used for counting number of people in department

```
SELECT count(*) as count,dept.dept_name
FROM employees 
INNER JOIN dept on employees.department_id = dept.department_id 
GROUP BY dept.dept_name;
```

How would I go about implementing it in a single query so that it meets the specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `HAVING` clause to your query, which restricts to only departments having an average salary less than 2000.

```
SELECT
    d.dept_id,
    d.dept_name,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN dept d
    ON e.department_id = d.department_id 
GROUP BY
    d.dept_id    -- or maybe GROUP BY d.dept_id, d.dept_name if this doesn't work
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) < 20 AND
    AVG(salary) < 2000;
```

A `WHERE` clause applies to individual records, but a `HAVING` clause applies to groups, after `GROUP BY` has run.  In this case, you want the latter.

**Edit:** You would be better off grouping by the `dept_id` column, as this should always be unique (and should be a primary key in this table).  The potential risk of grouping by department name is that two different departments might have the same name.

Comment: Could I use "AND" with HAVING CLAUSE to fulfill my query's need. I've italicized what my query needs.

Comment: When you select d.dept_name, dept_name isn't in employees. Could you explain?

Comment: @somethingelse Your select clause may, in theory, contain _any_ column from _any_ of the tables which appear after `FROM`.  In this case, it is more restrictive, but `dept.dept_name` is a totally valid column to select here.

Comment: I tried adding dept_id as another column, however the select group seems to be inconsistent. All dept_names and dept_ids are unique too.

Comment: The updated query in my answer should meet your needs.  I can't really comment further.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) as count,dept.dept_name, salary
FROM employees 
INNER JOIN dept on employees.department_id = dept.department_id 
GROUP BY dept.dept_name HAVING salary < 2000
```

Comment: Could I use "AND" with HAVING CLAUSE to fulfill my query's need. I've italicized what my query needs

Comment: @Murat Tüfekçi: that should be `AVG(salary)`.

Comment: @somethingelse: Yes, use `AND`. You could just have tried it or googled it rather than asking this question.

Comment: `SELECT count(*) as count,
dept.dept_name, 
AVG(employees.salary) as avgSalary
FROM employees 
INNER JOIN dept on employees.department_id = dept.department_id 
WHERE employees.department_id IN (
    SELECT dept_id
    FROM employees
    WHERE AVG(salary) < 2000 GROUP BY GROUP BY department_id
)
GROUP BY dept.department_id;`

Comment: Argh, no. Simply change `salary` to `AVG(employees.salaray)` in your original query and add `AND count(*) < 20` at the end of it.

Comment: add dept.department_id to selected fields and that's enough